# How do I need to structure my PHP code to work with and without jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am beginner to php and I am trying to develop a simple project to understand PHP and jQuery better. It is a simple registration and login system. I am also trying to use MVC structure. I have a "Member" class which contains a method named register. In this method, I simply check if there is a $_POST data on the top, and according to that information the method carries out the registration (if there is $_POST) or shows the registration form (if there isn't).

I am now trying to use jQuery. My problem is I do not know how do I need to construct my code. What is the best practise? I guess I have to split my code in two parts. However, I think using one page to show both registration form and carry out the registration is a more compact and cleaner solution. But with jQuery, I do not how I can do this. I also want this code to work when javascript is disabled.

Comment: _I am now trying to use jQuery._ - and for what purpose? What are you trying to achieve with jQuery?

Comment: Build your site entirely in PHP or any server side language. You will face no problem if js is disabled. What about if user decide to disable CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started and learn best practices you should check this out --> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

If Javascript disabled in browser then jquery won't work, on that case you can use CSS3.